# Error 403: Forbidden when trying to load pre-trained model in Google colab

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

Here is my code to load a pre-trained model in a Google Colab notebookL

```
# Import resources
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
import time
import json
import copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from collections import OrderedDict
import torch
from torch import nn, optim, cuda
from torch.optim import lr_scheduler
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets, models, transforms
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import os

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() 
                                  else "cpu")
print(device)

model = models.resnet152(pretrained=True) 
num_in_features = 2048
print(model)
```

I have run this line before with success, however now I get the error:

```
Downloading: "https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet152-b121ed2d.pth" to /root/.cache/torch/checkpoints/resnet152-b121ed2d.pth
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-361fc480b515> in <module>()
----> 1 model = models.resnet152(pretrained=True)
      2 num_in_features = 2048
      3 print(model)

9 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    651 
    652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I have tried loading the model in various other ways, starting a new notebook, and `!kill -9 -1`

I'm new to Google Colab and am not sure what the issue really is here! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem. (An HTTP 403 is likely a configuration issue with the hosting service underlying the modules package. In this case, I'm guessing pytorch.)

Comment: @BobSmith I updated my question to include all the code up until the error and the error message

Comment: Facing the same issue today when yesterday the same code was working...

Comment: An issue have been opened here : https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1876

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was an issue for lots of people and it is resolved now!

Answer (score 0):

```
torch.hub._validate_not_a_forked_repo=lambda a,b,c: True
```

This worked for me, found [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/61755#issuecomment-885801511).